# Convert time in the form mm:ss into seconds in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

Using Postgres 9.3.5

My table has duration data in the as a `text` field stored as minutes:seconds,

```
i.e 4:52
```

I want the value as total seconds (i.e 4 x 60) + 52 = 292

But table also contains values such as

```
3:34:21 (3 hours, 34  minutes and 21 seconds)
21 (21 seconds)
```

How can I write SQL to correct calculate duration in seconds for all these cases.

**Update**

```
select (case when duration like '%:%:%'
             then extract(epoch from duration::time)
             else extract(epoch from ('00:' || duration) ::time)
 end
)as seconds
from discogs.track t1
;
```

So I have this but unfortunately some values are not quite valid causing it to fail

```
00:70:01
```

How do I either ignore such values or convert them (i.e 70 x 60 + 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/19379

I expand `%:%` text to `%:%:%` texts and then simply split on delimiter ';'. So I am getting integer values which can be used in calculations.

```
SELECT 
    orig_duration,
    hours_in_seconds + minutes_in_seconds + seconds as seconds 
FROM (
    SELECT  
        orig_duration,
        (split_part(duration, ':', 1))::int * 60 * 60 as hours_in_seconds,
        (split_part(duration, ':', 2))::int * 60 as minutes_in_seconds,
        (split_part(duration, ':', 3))::int as seconds
    FROM (
        SELECT
            duration as orig_duration,
            case when duration like '%:%:%' then duration else '00:' || duration end as duration
        FROM (
            SELECT unnest(ARRAY['70:01','3:34:21','4:52']::text[]) as duration
        )s
    )s
)s
```

Result:

```
orig_duration  seconds  
-------------  -------  
70:01          4201     
3:34:21        12861    
4:52           292
```

Comment: Thanks I got something working based on your answer.

Comment: .. when I try on small record set but failing when ran over whole database - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897967/how-to-find-out-bad-data-causing-this-plsql-to-failing

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the value to time and extract the time component.  You do need to take the variable format into account:

```
select (case when t like '%:%:%'
             then extract(epoch from t::time)
             else extract(epoch from ('00:' || t) ::time)
        end) as seconds
```

You added a new format.  You can do:

```
select (case when t like '%:%:%'
             then extract(epoch from t::time)
             when t like '%:%'
             then extract(epoch from ('00:' || t) ::time)
             else t::int
        end) as seconds
```

Comment: Thanks but fail because of some invalid data please see updated date how do I resolve this.

Comment: @PaulTaylor . . . I think that is pretty easily fixed by adjusting the `case` expression.  This seems rather simpler than the other answer.

Comment: Thanks Gordon but I didnt really understand what epoch or extract did so I went with a solution I could work into my solution

Comment: @PaulTaylor . . . You should learn.  They do exactly what you are asking for, which is extracting the total number of seconds from a date/time field.

Comment: but it wasnt a datetime field it was a string purporting to be a time field but containing non standard values. I learn alot of things but I feel yo are giving me a hard time because I picked someone elses answer over yours.

Comment: @PaulTaylor. . . Not exactly.  You are the OP and can choose whichever answer you prefer -- and for whatever reason.  On occasion, I don't think a better or equivalent answer is accepted, and I'm curious why.  I should have made that clear up front.